# Resizable Toolbar with bar button on UIDate Picker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, uitoolbar, landscape-portrait

I have used date picker at place of keypad.And UI bar Button With ok,cancel and Flexible space.
But It is not responsive when i change Portrait to LandScape mode.

Tool Bar:-

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    toolbar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;


    cancelBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
    flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"OK"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBtn,flexible,doneBtn,nil]];


     [toolbar sizeToFit];
    _txt_dob.inputAccessoryView=datePicker;
```

UIDate Picker:-

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [_txt_dob setInputView:datePicker];
    [datePicker addSubview:toolbar];
```

[image: Portrait Mode]

LandScape Mode of Simulator.
[image: LandScape Mode]

Comment: Have you use autolayout?

Comment: set toolbar frame in view `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah Width of toolbar is self.view.frame.size.width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not initialize your `UIToolBar` with frame. Instead use `NSLayoutConstraint` between your `UIToolBar` and its parent view to stretch it all the way. That way it will respond well to orientation changes.